# Color child elements with border height on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with 2 anchor child elements. The parent div has a border, and on hover, I wish to highlight the child anchor tags. Now, I can do this, but the hover doesn't fill up the entire width and height of the border that surrounds the parent div.

```css
.header-info {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.about-header-container {
  width: 240px;
  border: 10px solid #027878;
}
.about-header-container>a:hover {
  background-color: #027878;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class='about-header-container header-info' id='about-header'>
  <a class='bio-header tablink' href='#bio-dashfolio'>Bio</a>
  <a class='timeline-header tablink' href='#timeline-dashfolio'> Timeline</a>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kesh92/3cnxef4h/

On hovering over **Bio** and **Timeline**, I want it to highlight to the color `#027878` while filling up the appropriate section inside the border without leaving any white spaces between the border and the anchor elements. Thanks in advance!

**Update**
This is the desired hover effect -

Before hover 
 [image: List item]

When hovering over Bio
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Didn't realised you wanted to fill both the height and width. This one will do the trick:

```
.tablink {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

On your .header-info change padding: 5px; to padding: 0 5px;

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cba0cn7n/1/

And use the code below to fill the height only

```
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 0;
```

to your .tablink

What is being done here is removing the padding-top and bottom from .header-info and adding it to the .tablink.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply! What you're suggesting, and please correct me if I'm wrong, is to change the anchor elements padding so they can better fit the parent border. 

I already have the styles in place. What I want to do is to highlight the anchor elements on hover to fill the right and left sections of the border respectively. 
Please see the updated question as I've added the desired result. Thnks!

Comment: Hi Keshav, I messed up with the fiddle link but now I got it right. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/cba0cn7n/1/ check if it is what you are looking for. I'm glad to help

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can you please explain what I did wrong? I'm still not fully clear as to how you solution did the trick :) I

Comment: Oh I understood it,  no need for explanation! :D

Comment: Cool. If you have any other doubt just tell me. I'll do my best to explain